# Half of the skinny lovely ghost, plus the earth and the sun

Tags: riddle

1. I am either your love or a ghost
2. I am a synonym for thin
3. I am all, but not the whole
4. I am the earth
5. I am the sun

And altogether, I am either true or false

Comment: Is the title part of the riddle or just you asking for help?  Welcome to Puzzling, Dodo

Comment: The title is not part of the riddle, I am actually asking for help

Comment: I edited for what I assume are just mistakes.  If the spelling or grammar are intentional, feel free to role it back

Comment: It appears you found this riddle elsewhere. Could you please give a source for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding on to @Pugmonkey's answer:

> It's Boolean Algebra.

Either your love or a ghost:

> Boo

A synonym for thin:

> lean

All, but not the whole:

> al(the last letter is missing)

The earth:

> geb(the god of earth)

The sun:

> ra(the god of sun)

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

1. I am either your love or a ghost

> Boo

2. I am a synonym for thin

> Lean

3.I am all, but not the whole

4.I am the earth

5.I am the sun

And altogether, I am either true or false

> Boolean ______________